# patching \setcounter and \addotocounter not working well with calc

Tags: counters, etoolbox, calc

for some very specific needs of reledac, I need to get the value of the page counter each time it is changed, either via `settocounter`, either with `addotcounter`.

So I did something like this (it is a very simplified example, and in reality, I dont typeset directly the counter).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
%\usepackage{calc}
\makeatletter
\newcount\this@c@page
\newcommand{\set@this@c@page}{\global\this@c@page=\value{page}}
\apptocmd{\setcounter}{%
  \relax\IfStrEq{#1}{page}{\set@this@c@page}{}%
  }%
  {\PackageWarning{mypackage}{success}}%
  {\PackageWarning{mypackage}{fail}}%
\apptocmd{\addtocounter}{%
  \relax\IfStrEq{#1}{page}{\set@this@c@page}{}%
  }%
  {\PackageWarning{mypackage}{success}}%
  {\PackageWarning{mypackage}{fail}}%
\begin{document}
s
\newpage
\the\this@c@page
\end{document}
```

All work well, except if I use the `calc` package. In this case, `this@c@page` is still equal to 0. It seems the redefinition of the macro with this package change something to the time we can get the counter value, but I don't undestand why.

Any tricks ?

Comment: Section 2 of the `calc` manual speaks a little of this (modifying `\setcounter` and `\addtocounter`): https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/calc.pdf

Comment: Yes, I read it. It explained why these change, but not the consequencies. I remember that I did have similar problem with setlength modification, but I was able to turn around using directly TeX dimen. For this problem, I must deal with LaTeX counter...

Comment: I did not mean to imply it told you how to fix it.  Rather, it might be a place for someone to begin looking.

Comment: Ah, oki. Yes, indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page counter is incremented using `\stepcounter` which is also updated by [`calc`](//ctan.org/pkg/calc). Here is the definition of `\stepcounter` before loading `calc` (as contained within the kernel [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co)):

```
\def\stepcounter#1{%
  \addtocounter{#1}\@ne
  \begingroup
    \let\@elt\@stpelt
    \csname cl@#1\endcsname
  \endgroup}
```

Note how `\stepcounter` uses `\addtocounter`, which you've updated and hence works as expected. Here's the new definition of `\stepcounter` (redefined by `calc`):

```
\def\stepcounter#1{\@ifundefined {c@#1}%
  {\@nocounterr {#1}}%
  {\global\advance\csname c@#1\endcsname \@ne
  \begingroup
    \let\@elt\@stpelt \csname cl@#1\endcsname
  \endgroup}}%
```

With `calc`, `\stepcounter` doesn't use `\addtocounter`, hence no update to the `page` counter or the way you're capturing it.

To fix this, you'll have to update `\stepcounter` in the same way you've done for `\setcounter` and `\addtocounter`:

```
\apptocmd{\stepcounter}{%
  \relax\IfStrEq{#1}{page}{\set@this@c@page}{}%
  }%
  {\PackageWarning{mypackage}{success}}%
  {\PackageWarning{mypackage}{fail}}%
```

`calc` mentions that the update to `\setcounter` is to avoid having to go through "the entire `calc` process" (via `\addtocounter`).

Comment: How yes of course ! I was looking on addtocounter redefinition, but not to stepcounter redefinition. Thank you ! I am so stupid.